# How to detect any changes performed on any object (OU, Container, Computers or Users) in an Active Directory?

Tags: networking, active-directory

Suppose there is an active directory, how to check or detect for any changes like add, delete, modify or even moving an object from one OU or container to another.

Edit : Is there any way to perform this using the LDAP Queries ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 documented ways to track AD changes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677625(v=vs.85).aspx